# How to search a string with regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using an include function to validate if a string contains a sub-string:

```
let string = "!ruby/object:RPG::EventCommand {i: 1, c: 401, p: ['User can input ANY string here']}";

console.log(string.includes("!ruby/object:RPG::EventCommand {i: " + /\d+/ + ", c: 401, p:"));
// Output is false, needs to be true
```

My problem is that the " i " property in this string can be any digit so I attempted to use a regular expression /\d+/ in order to validate it no matter the digit present in that property, but it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

```
"!ruby/object:RPG::EventCommand {i: " + /\d+/ + ", c: 401, p:
// resolves to
'!ruby/object:RPG::EventCommand {i: /\\d+/, c: 401, p:'
>
```

The concatenation removes the regular expression. This can be solved by writing the entire search term as a regular expresssion.

```
/!ruby\/object:RPG::EventCommand {i: \d+, c: 401, p:/
```